# Imported package searches for modules in my code

Tags: python, import, module, pytorch, package

Can someone explain me what is going on here and how to prevent this?

I have a **main.py** with the following code:

```python
import utils
import torch


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Foo
    print("Foo")

    # Bar
    utils.bar()

    model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5s")
```

I outsourced some functions into a module named **utils.py**:

```python
def bar():
    print("Bar")
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
(venv) jan@xxxxx test % python main.py
Foo
Bar
Using cache found in /Users/jan/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jan/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5s")
File "/Users/jan/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 540, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jan/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 569, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jan/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 81, in yolov5s
    return _create('yolov5s', pretrained, channels, classes, autoshape, _verbose, device)
File "/Users/jan/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 31, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
File "/Users/jan/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 24, in <module>
    from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.dataloaders'; 'utils' is not a package
```

So it seems like the **torch** package I imported has also a **utils** resource (package) and searches for a module named "utils.dataloaders". Okay. But why is it searching in my utils module? And why isn't it continuing searching in its own package if it doesn't find a matching resource in my code? And last but not least: How can I prevent this situation?

I changed `import utils` to `import utils as ut` and call my function with `ut.bar()` but it doesn't make any difference.

The only thing that worked is to **rename** my `utils.py` to something else but this cannot be the solution...

Thanks for your help. Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other `utils` package does not belong to torch, it belongs to the yolov5 repository: `/Users/jan/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils`.

Now, to explain the error: It seems that python would search for `sys.modules` first when you import `utils`. If you import your own `utils` first, it is registered in `sys.modules`, and python would search in your own `utils` for things needed for the yolov5 model. Same thing would happen if you create the model first and import your own `utils` later (at this time, `utils` of the yolov5 repo is registered in `sys.modules`, so you won't be able to import your own `utils`).

The easiest solution would be to rename your `utils.py`, or put it under a folder, e.g.,

```bash
your_project/
  main.py
  some_name_other_than_utils/
    utils.py
```

and import it as

```py
import some_name_other_than_utils.utils as utils
```

Then, `some_name_other_than_utils.utils` is registered in `sys.modules` so it won't affect importing in yolov5.

Another solution is to copy the yolov5 folder as a subfolder of your project. So everything in the yolov5 folder is under another namespace, without conflicting with your files. But you may need to change some import statements, and replace `torch.hub.load` with your own model loading function.

---

In most cases, having `utils` in your own project shouldn't conflict with third-party software that also has `utils`. If you try to import torch and then check sys.modules, you can see `torch.utlis`, `torch.nn.utils`, etc., rather than just `utils`. The following is an example of how this can be done with relative imports:

```bash
your_project/
  main.py
  utils.py
  some_3rdparty_lib/
    __init__.py
    utils.py
```

In `some_3rdparty_lib/__init__.py`:

```py
# some_3rdparty_lib/__init__.py
from . import utils
```

Then in `main.py`:

```py
# main.py
import utils   # your own utils
import some_3rdparty_lib.utils   # the one under some_3rdparty_lib
```

Note that `some_3rdparty_lib` does not have to be under your project directory. You can put it anywhere as long as the path is in `sys.path`. The imported `utils` would still belong to the namespace `some_3rdparty_lib`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, makes it easier to understand this situation.
But wouldn't that mean, if a common imported package (like numpy for example) would have an intern ```utils``` module or package, you can't have a custom ```utils``` package in your own project? I think that would be odd since 'utils' is a common naming convention to make clear that some helper functions are outsourced.

Comment: @jani In most cases, a `utils` package of third-party software would be imported under some namespace. If you try to import `torch` and then check `sys.modules`, you can see `torch.utlis`, `torch.nn.utils`, etc., rather than just `utils`. If you check the source for `torch.hub`, it inserts the cached yolov5 repo path to `sys.path`, so the import of `utils` does not come with a namespace.

Comment: @jani Added an example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of the file from utils to another name because maybe you installed utils package before so the python automatically get the package and ignore your utils.py file.

make your file name plapla.py

```
import plapla
```

maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run "pip list" there is no package utils. And as I mentioned in my question, this would be a workaround, but isn't there another solution? This would mean, that if a common imported package has an intern module or package named "utils", I cannot have a custom utils module or package in my own project?!

Comment: your utils.py is a python file that include class right?

Comment: What do you mean by 'include class'? There is no class in my utils.py. The whole content of this file are the two lines, listed in my question above.

Comment: you should create a class there to get the functions i will explain it with code in other answer